# Magento 2.2 : getcollection is not working in the Block

Tags: magento2, module, custom, model, magento2.2

My custom collection is not working in block file Helloworld.php

```
<?php
namespace New\MyModule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Helloworld extends Template
{
    protected $_modelFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                New\MyModule\Model\DataFactory $modelFactory,
                                array $data = array())
    {
        $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getHelloCollection()
        {
            return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();
        }
}
```

Model files:

> Model\Data.php

```
<?php


namespace New\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

    class Data extends AbstractModel
    {   
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('New\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Data');
        }
    }
```

Resource model:

> Model\ResourceModel\Data.php

```
<?php

namespace New\MyModel\Model\ResourceModel;


use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Data extends AbstractDb

{

    protected function _construct()

    {

        $this->_init('blog_posts', 'post_id');

    }

}
```

Collection file:

> New\MyModule\model\ResourceModel\Data\Collection.php

```
<?php


namespace New\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Data;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;


class Collection extends AbstractCollection

{

    protected function _construct()
    {

        $this->_init(
        'New\MyModule\Model\Data',
        'New\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Data');

    }

}
```

I need to get the collection into my block to fetch the database values. pls help me.

Comment: any error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tested this code and find out only one error

Change

```
public function __construct(Context $context,
                                New\MyModule\Model\DataFactory $modelFactory,
                                array $data = array())
    {
        $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

to

```
public function __construct(Context $context,
                                \New\MyModule\Model\DataFactory $modelFactory,
                                array $data = array())
    {
        $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

Below is my code

QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\Helloworld.php

```
<?php


     namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model;



    class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel  
    {   
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld');
        }
    }
```

QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld.php

```
<?php

namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel;


use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Helloworld extends AbstractDb

{

    protected function _construct()

    {

        $this->_init('blog_posts', 'post_id');

    }

}
```

QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld\Collection.php

```
<?php


namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;


class Collection extends AbstractCollection

{

    protected function _construct()
    {

        $this->_init(
        'QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\Helloworld',
        'QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Helloworld');

    }

}
```

BLock file

QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld.php

```
<?php 


namespace QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_helloworldFactory;
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
      \QaisarSatti\HelloWorld\Model\HelloworldFactory $helloworldFactory,      
       array $data = []
   ) {


       $this->_helloworldFactory = $helloworldFactory;

       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
   public function getHelloCollection()
        {
            return $this->_helloworldFactory->create()->getCollection();
        }

}
```

[Source link](https://github.com/kingsatti/magento2_custommodel)

Comment: thanks, Everything i did the same.. but still i can't able to get the collection in my block... Can i see ur block file.. it will be helpful.

Comment: @SelvaKumar add the block file too and don't forgot to delete `var/generation` folder

Comment: I am following your steps. Now I am the getcollection method as deprecated with strikeout line.

Comment: @SelvaKumar which magento version?

Comment: magento  version 2.2

Comment: @SelvaKumar i test this code with 2.2.1 and find no error.

Comment: thanks, can u provide me the source code. it will be helpful for me.

Comment: @SelvaKumar added the complete code in answer.

Comment: Hi @QaisarSatti. It seems same question except eav. Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264128/magento-2-addattributetofilter-addattributetoselect-addfieldtofilter-not-wor/264130