# Magento2.2 getCollection from Factory deprecated

Tags: collection, magento2.2, deprecated

I get in my editor (PhPStorm) on getCollection the message that it is deprecated.

In my controller i got the function

```
public function __construct(
    Registry $registry,
    TableRepositoryInterface $dataRepository,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
    Manager $messageManager,
    TableInterfaceFactory $dataFactory,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    Context $context,
    Logger $logger,
    DirectoryList $directoryList,
    File $ioFile,
    Menu $helper,
    Costs $costsModel,
    CostsRepositoryInterface $costsRepository,
    CostsFactory $costsFactory
) {
    $this->costsFactory     = $costsFactory;
    $this->costsRepository  = $costsRepository;
    $this->costsModel       = $costsModel;
    $this->helper           = $helper;
    $this->ioFile           = $ioFile;
    $this->directoryList    = $directoryList;
    $this->logger           = $logger;
    $this->messageManager   = $messageManager;
    $this->dataFactory      = $dataFactory;
    $this->dataRepository   = $dataRepository;
    $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
    parent::__construct($registry, $dataRepository, $resultPageFactory, $resultForwardFactory, $context, $logger);
}
```

And here i call the function

```
public function existingColorRange($data)
{
    // Check the color_amount/from/till with database
    $costsCollection = $this->costsFactory->create()->getCollection();
}
```

Got my model build just like in following 
[link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203311/magento-2-2-getcollection-is-not-working-in-the-block/203326)

How do i call the collection the right way without deprecated function?

Comment: Have you found your question's answer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issue and after digging through core code and reviewing generated classes, I found how.

If you look in `vendor/magento/modulecatalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php`

Notice:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
```

In the constructor, we're expecting a CollectionFactory instance. If you look at the dynamically generated factory class you'll see:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category;

/**
 * Factory class for @see \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
 */
class CollectionFactory
{
    /**
     * Object Manager instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager = null;

    /**
     * Instance name to create
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_instanceName = null;

    /**
     * Factory constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param string $instanceName
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, $instanceName = '\\Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Category\\Collection')
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_instanceName = $instanceName;
    }

    /**
     * Create class instance with specified parameters
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     */
    public function create(array $data = array())
    {
        return $this->_objectManager->create($this->_instanceName, $data);
    }
}
```

Where the instance name is the collection.

In your case, change:

```
CostsFactory $costsFactory
```

To:

```
CostsCollectionFactory $costsFactory

use Example\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel\Cost\CollectionFactory as CostsCollectionFactory;
```

Then you can use the collection like so:

```
$costsCollection = $this->costsFactory->create();

$costsCollection->addFieldToSelect(...)
$costsCollection->addFieldToFilter(...)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Create Your Collection Model

Create class `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Costs\Collection` in file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Costs/Collection.php`, codes like below

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Costs;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Costs;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Costs as CostsResource;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'id';

    /**
     * Initialize resource collection.
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            Costs::class,
            CostsResource::class
        );
    }
}
```

### 2. Get the Collection

In your class, write codes like below, the function `getCollection` is exactly what you need.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Costs\CollectionFactory;

class CostsRepository
{
    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->collectionFactory->create();
    }
}
```