# Magento2 Alternate of Method getCollection() which is deprecated

Tags: magento2, collection, factory, deprecated

I have checked the similar post: [Magento2.2 getCollection from Factory deprecated](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204512/magento2-2-getcollection-from-factory-deprecated)

But I still don't find the answer of it. I am calling `getCollection()` function, and PHPStorm saying that this function is deprecated.

```
$this->_myCollectionFactory->create()->getCollection()
```

where `$this->_myCollectionFactory` is the instance of my collection factory which is `\Vendor\Module\Model\ModuleFactory`.

And this is my `ModuleFactory` class code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class ModuleFactory
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * Create new country model
     *
     * @param array $arguments
     * @return \Magento\Directory\Model\Country
     */
    public function create(array $arguments = [])
    {
        return $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Module', $arguments, false);
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the alternate of getCollection if it is deprecated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shoaib Munir ,you are wrong as `$this->_myCollectionFactory` instance of a  collection faCTORY CLASS . If you have using **Collection factory class then getting collection data**, you don't need to call method `getCollection`.Also `getCollection` is **not the method of collection class** and it is the method of  Model class Like `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`.

If you have a **collection class then you need to use the code  like below**

`$collection =  $this->_myCollectionFactory->create()`

Comment: Updated my answer, added more info. `getCollection()` code is working fine and it is getting my collection, but phpStorm giving warning that the function is deprecated.

Comment: Please check your  commit `where $this->_myCollectionFactory is the instance of my collection factory which is \Vendor\Module\Model\ModuleFactory` .How can a Modelfactory  class is collection factory class???. Please understand  Model,ResourceModel,Collection class and their factory class

Comment: Is this solution is applicable for previous versions of Magento 2?

Comment: Got your point now. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a `CollectionFactory`as follows. 
For example, for `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` :

```
public function __construct(    
  \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
) {
  $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory; 
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
  return $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Amit bera gave answer first. +1 for your efforts and help :)

Answer (score 3):

In Magento2 it is always recommend using **Search Criteria** to get collections
For example:

```
   $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('zip', $saveSearchZip['zip'], 'eq')
        ->addFilter('country', $saveSearchZip['country'], 'eq')
        ->addFilter('latitude', $saveSearchZip['latitude'], 'eq')
        ->addFilter('longitude', $saveSearchZip['longitude'], 'eq');

   $collection = $myModuleRepositoryInterfaceObject->getList($searchCriteriaBuilder->create());
```

Please give a refer [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/searching-with-repositories.html) for better understanding. Also find [sample module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-servicecontract-new)

Comment: what is the instance of `$searchCriteriaBuilder`? is it collection factory?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder::class , i have also included documentation for it please go through it it would be helpful

Comment: what if my collection is related to a custom table? how can I get my collection through search criteria?

Comment: I am assuming that that you have created a module for custom, So as per magento standards you have to create repository interface for it . so you can use that repo interface  myModuleRepositoryInterfaceObject

Comment: No Vishawas this is not related to customer, this is custom module of a custom table collection.

Comment: Sorry i ment custom ,i have added sample module for your reference