# Magento 2 : addAttributeToFilter, addAttributeToSelect, addFieldToFilter not working

Tags: magento2, collection, eav, eav-attributes

I created eav entity module. But, when I use this `addAttributeToFilter, addAttributeToSelect, addFieldToFilter` function in my custom module collection. It's not working.

**My collection file :**

I extend `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection`

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Mainpage;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Eav\Model\EntityFactory as EavEntityFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class Collection
 * @package VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Mainpage
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * @var $_storeId
     */
    protected $_storeId;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    const KEY_MAIN_VIDEO_TITLE = 'main_video_title';


    /**
     * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param Config $eavConfig
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param EavEntityFactory $eavEntityFactory
     * @param Helper $resourceHelper
     * @param UniversalFactory $universalFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param AdapterInterface $connection
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        Config $eavConfig,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        EavEntityFactory $eavEntityFactory,
        Helper $resourceHelper,
        UniversalFactory $universalFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        AdapterInterface $connection = null
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $eavConfig,
            $resource,
            $eavEntityFactory,
            $resourceHelper,
            $universalFactory,
            $connection
        );
    }

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Mainpage::class, \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Mainpage::class);
    }

    /**
     * Set store scope
     *
     * @param int|string|\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStore($store)
    {
        $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore($store)->getId());
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set store scope
     *
     * @param int|string|\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $storeId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStoreId($storeId)
    {
        if ($storeId instanceof \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface) {
            $storeId = $storeId->getId();
        }
        $this->_storeId = (int)$storeId;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Return current store id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        if ($this->_storeId === null) {
            $this->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        }
        return $this->_storeId;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve default store id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDefaultStoreId()
    {
        return \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID;
    }

     /**
     * Set main video title
     *
     * @param int $mainvideoTitle
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMainVideoTitle($mainvideoTitle)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_MAIN_VIDEO_TITLE, $mainvideoTitle);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getMainVideoTitle()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::KEY_MAIN_VIDEO_TITLE);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve attributes load select
     *
     * @param string $table
     * @param array|int $attributeIds
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection
     */
    protected function _getLoadAttributesSelect($table, $attributeIds = [])
    {
        if (empty($attributeIds)) {
            $attributeIds = $this->_selectAttributes;
        }
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        $entityTable = $this->getEntity()->getEntityTable();
        $indexList = $connection->getIndexList($entityTable);
        $entityIdField = $indexList[$connection->getPrimaryKeyName($entityTable)]['COLUMNS_LIST'][0];

        if ($storeId) {
            $joinCondition = [
                't_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id',
                "t_s.{$entityIdField} = t_d.{$entityIdField}",
                $connection->quoteInto('t_s.store_id = ?', $storeId),
            ];

            $select = $connection->select()->from(
                ['t_d' => $table],
                ['attribute_id']
            )->join(
                ['e' => $entityTable],
                "e.{$entityIdField} = t_d.{$entityIdField}",
                ['e.entity_id']
            )->where(
                "e.entity_id IN (?)",
                array_keys($this->_itemsById)
            )->where(
                't_d.attribute_id IN (?)',
                $attributeIds
            )->joinLeft(
                ['t_s' => $table],
                implode(' AND ', $joinCondition),
                []
            )->where(
                't_d.store_id = ?',
                $connection->getIfNullSql('t_s.store_id', \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID)
            );
        } else {
            $select = $connection->select()->from(
                ['t_d' => $table],
                ['attribute_id']
            )->join(
                ['e' => $entityTable],
                "e.{$entityIdField} = t_d.{$entityIdField}",
                ['e.entity_id']
            )->where(
                "e.entity_id IN (?)",
                array_keys($this->_itemsById)
            )->where(
                'attribute_id IN (?)',
                $attributeIds
            )->where(
                'store_id = ?',
                $this->getDefaultStoreId()
            );
        }
        return $select;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select
     * @param string $table
     * @param string $type
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select
     */
    protected function _addLoadAttributesSelectValues($select, $table, $type)
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        if ($storeId) {
            $connection = $this->getConnection();
            $valueExpr = $connection->getCheckSql('t_s.value_id IS NULL', 't_d.value', 't_s.value');

            $select->columns(
                ['default_value' => 't_d.value', 'store_value' => 't_s.value', 'value' => $valueExpr]
            );
        } else {
            $select = parent::_addLoadAttributesSelectValues($select, $table, $type);
        }
        return $select;
    }

    /**
     * Adding join statement to collection select instance
     *
     * @param string $method
     * @param object $attribute
     * @param string $tableAlias
     * @param array $condition
     * @param string $fieldCode
     * @param string $fieldAlias
     * @return \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection
     */
    protected function _joinAttributeToSelect($method, $attribute, $tableAlias, $condition, $fieldCode, $fieldAlias)
    {
        if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$fieldCode]['store_id'])) {
            $storeId = $this->_joinAttributes[$fieldCode]['store_id'];
        } else {
            $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
        }

        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        if ($storeId != $this->getDefaultStoreId() && !$attribute->isScopeGlobal()) {
            $defCondition = '(' . implode(') AND (', $condition) . ')';
            $defAlias = $tableAlias . '_default';
            $defAlias = $this->getConnection()->getTableName($defAlias);
            $defFieldAlias = str_replace($tableAlias, $defAlias, $fieldAlias);
            $tableAlias = $this->getConnection()->getTableName($tableAlias);

            $defCondition = str_replace($tableAlias, $defAlias, $defCondition);
            $defCondition .= $connection->quoteInto(
                " AND " . $connection->quoteColumnAs("{$defAlias}.store_id", null) . " = ?",
                $this->getDefaultStoreId()
            );

            $this->getSelect()->{$method}(
                [$defAlias => $attribute->getBackend()->getTable()],
                $defCondition,
                []
            );

            $method = 'joinLeft';
            $fieldAlias = $this->getConnection()->getCheckSql(
                "{$tableAlias}.value_id > 0",
                $fieldAlias,
                $defFieldAlias
            );
            $this->_joinAttributes[$fieldCode]['condition_alias'] = $fieldAlias;
            $this->_joinAttributes[$fieldCode]['attribute'] = $attribute;
        } else {
            $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreId();
        }
        $condition[] = $connection->quoteInto(
            $connection->quoteColumnAs("{$tableAlias}.store_id", null) . ' = ?',
            $storeId
        );
        return parent::_joinAttributeToSelect($method, $attribute, $tableAlias, $condition, $fieldCode, $fieldAlias);
    }
}
```

How to do that, this all function should be working as like working in product collection and all.

**My code :**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \VendorName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Mainpage\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    )
    {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
    * Default customer account page
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('main_video_title','Main Page Title German'); //main_video_title is my attribute
        print_r($collection->getData());
    }
}
?>
```

Tables :

**vendor_module_entity :**

[image]

**vendor_module_entity_varchar :**

[image]

I debug in core function and I get proper query as like product collection query :

> SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) AS `name` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
>   INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (`at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '73') AND `at_name_default`.`store_id` = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (`at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_name`.`attribute_id` = '73') AND (`at_name`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_name.value_id > 0, at_name.value, at_name_default.value) = 'Push It Messenger Bag')

It returns 1 record

============================

My Module Query :

> SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_main_video_title.value_id > 0, at_main_video_title.value, at_main_video_title_default.value) AS `main_video_title` FROM `vendor_module_entity` AS `e`
>   INNER JOIN `vendor_module_entity_varchar` AS `at_main_video_title_default` ON (`at_main_video_title_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_main_video_title_default`.`attribute_id` = '190') AND `at_main_video_title_default`.`store_id` = 0
>   LEFT JOIN `vendor_module_entity_varchar` AS `at_main_video_title` ON (`at_main_video_title`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_main_video_title`.`attribute_id` = '190') AND (`at_main_video_title`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE (IF(at_main_video_title.value_id > 0, at_main_video_title.value, at_main_video_title_default.value) = 'Main Page Title German')

It returns blank array.

Comment: Have you checked by printing query using get Select()

Comment: Yes. It's SELECT `e`.* FROM `vendor_module_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`main_video_title` = 'Main Page Title German')

Comment: I think i need to apply join.

Comment: Hi @RamkishanSuthar please check my updated question.

Comment: did you tried `print_r($collection->load()->getData());`

Comment: Yes. It's return blank array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection works correct in my opinion, the data you look for is in store 2. So you just need to set the store id in your collection.

```
$collection->setStoreId(2)->addAttributeToFilter('main_video_title','Main Page Title German');
```

Comment: Cool...!!! It's working. Can you please tell me just one thing how addAttributeToSelect working? I added $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setStoreId(2)->addAttributeToSelect(['main_video_title','main_video_url','main_video_desc'])->addAttributeToFilter('main_video_title',['eq' => 'Main Page Title German']); But, main_video_url and main_video_desc not display in array.

Comment: Try to remove all protected methods `_getLoadAttributesSelect`, `_addLoadAttributesSelectValues` and `_joinAttributeToSelect` from your code, use implictit those from parent class and see what happens. As far as I see you have copied a part of the code from catalog module maybe that has impact

Comment: Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/264236/17154

Comment: can you please help me..? When I use addFieldToFilter, it's not working. why?